# OkHttp post streaming - switching from cellular to WiFi

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm using `OkHttp` to stream files up to the server. My code looks something like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.builder()
        .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
        .build();

Response response = null;
try {
        RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody() {
            private long uploadedBytes;

            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                // return type based on file
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = source.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    sink.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                source.close();
            }
        }

        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(uploadUrl)
                    .put(requestBody)
                    // header stuff
                    .build();

        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle
}
```

In my code I'm streaming files (bytes) and my timeout set on the `OkHttpClient` is 20 seconds.

So, this is my scenario - a user is uploading a file on LTE when the phone connects to a WiFi spot. Right now what happens is that OkHttp continues to upload for some time (which I think is the timeout value but I'm not too sure), then fails with a broken pipe.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x74a6315680: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:824)
    at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:78)
    ...
```

At that point the task is rescheduled and picked up on WiFi whenever `JobScheduler` feels like it. So all in all, the switch between LTE and WiFi becomes quite painful and takes up to 30 seconds on a good day (timeout plus scheduler).

Considering that the reverse scenario works perfectly fine (WiFi -> LTE), I was hoping maybe there's something in `OkHttp` that I could use to improve this transition? My version of `OkHttp` is 3.4.1

Comment: Interesting question.  You might be able to reduce the delay by [monitoring the connection type](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) and rescheduling the job when it changes.

Comment: That's actually a great idea, thank you. Ideally I'd like to avoid relying on `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` as per recommendations in https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html - Project Svelte: Background Optimizations, however I could schedule a task in `JobScheduler` to cancel an upload task if there is one ongoing via LTE and WiFi is now available. That could work.

Comment: I don't think they're recommending against using `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`.  It's just that you will only receive it if your app is already running.

Comment: Yeah, but this phrasing `If your app uses any of these intents, you should remove dependencies on them as soon as possible so that you can target Android 7.0 devices properly` makes me think they might take it out completely in a future release